# Trouble building rust project with paho-mqtt on Mac OS 10.15.5

Tags: macos, rust, paho, rust-cargo

I have a rust project including

```
paho-mqtt = "0.7.1"
```

it's building on Linux but when I try to build it on my Macbook (OS 10.15.5) I receive the following error:

```
debug:Target: x86_64-apple-darwin

--- stderr
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libpaho-mqtt3cs.a(SHA1.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libpaho-mqtt3as.a(SHA1.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libpaho-mqtt3as.a(SHA1.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libpaho-mqtt3cs.a(SHA1.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: <path>target/debug/build/paho-mqtt-sys-a0f4fc80f95f5c23/out/lib/libpaho-mqtt3cs.a(SHA1.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: <path>target/debug/build/paho-mqtt-sys-a0f4fc80f95f5c23/out/lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.a(SHA1.c.o) has no symbols
thread 'main' panicked at 'No generated bindings exist for the version/target: bindings/bindings_paho_mqtt_c_1.3.2-x86_64-apple-darwin.rs', <path>/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/paho-mqtt-sys-0.3.0/build.rs:102:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

- `/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version` prints

```
Xcode 11.5
Build version 11E608c
```